# Is variable type declaration needed in Python when value comes from user input?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As I have understood, in Python(I am using 2.7.2+) variable type declaration happens automatically based on the value added to variable. If I assign an integer to variable named `nr` and would like to subtract 1 from this variable like this:

```
nr = raw_input("Word: ");
number = nr - 1
```

..then I end up with the `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'` error. Now if I specify that my input will be integer like this:

```
nr = int(raw_input("Word: "));
number = nr - 1
```

..then I'm able to complete the subtraction. Why is it needed to declare the variable type in this time?

Comment: You are not declaring the variable type. You are calling a function that converts a string to an int.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Ok, I see. So Python will put my variables automatically into one of the possible variable types(integer, float, string, boolean to name some) and if I need to perform operations with variables, then I need to ensure that variables are in the same type and if they are not, I can convert like `var=5; type(str(var))` or `var=True; type(str(True))`?

Comment: No, Python doesn't do anything automatically. It's just that `raw_input` *always* returns a string. But for subtraction you need numbers.

Comment: Seems like you are making confusion between duck typing (which Python has) and automatic conversion (which Python does not have, at least in this case).

Comment: @LevLevitsky, @StefanoSanfilippo I see. But if I define `var = 5` or `var2 = True` then Python automatically classifies those variables in one if the possible variable types because of duck typing? And if I need to perform operations with those variables, then I need to ensure that variables are in the same type and if they are not, I can convert them?

Comment: When you do `var = 5`, then `var` stores the value of `5`. Python doesn't really classify it, because it never does any checking. When you call `int(mystr)`, nothing happens to `mystr`, the function `int()` just returns a value (an `int`) and you can use it.

Comment: This piece of documentation may help: [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in `python-2.7`, `raw_input` reads in the input as a string by default. Therefore, if you want to perform mathematical operations on it, you have to [cast](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/interesting-casting-in-python) it as an `int`.

```
>>> number = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
Enter a number: 5
>>> print number
'5'
>>> type(number)
<type 'str'>
```

Whereas, if you cast it as an int, you get the following:

```
>>> number = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
Enter a number: 5
>>> print number
5
>>> type(number)
<type 'int'>
```

Python does not need you to declare a variable type, however, if you want a string value to be treated as an `int`, you have to cast it as an `int`. And that is what `int` does.

```
>>> print int('56')
56
```

Answer (score 2):

`int()` is not a declaration but a conversion function from string to integer. This is because Python will not attempt any tricky automatic conversion for the sake of clarity and least astonishment principle.

Conversely, if you take PHP, this will work:

```
"12" - 2
```

and this will work too:

```
"foo" - 2
```

but expect a bug coming any moment if you happen to be a bit careless about the exact behaviour of the two snippets above (string or integer difference? Is the result a string or an integer? If integer, what happens to `"foo"`?) , not to mention any more complex case.

Answer (score 1):

Because `raw_input` returns a string and python has no default behaviour for `str - int`. E.g.:

```
>>> "2" - 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
>>>
```

This is necessary every time you are doing an operation between two different types and python needs to figure out which implicit conversion to use: **you** know that "2" is a number, but what if you had `"a" - 1`?